# WCF Unit Testing Results in a System.ServiceModel.FaultException

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, exception

So I have a WCF service that seems to work perfectly in a deployed production environment.  My build intermittently fails though during the unit testing of this WCF service.  The weird part is that it's not always the same unit test, but it is always a unit test which uses the WCF service.

Exception:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException[System.ServiceModel.ExceptionDetail]: The number of bytes available is inconsistent with the HTTP Content-Length header.  There may have been a network error or the client may be sending invalid requests.
```

The weird part is that the exception really only happens on the build machine and never on a developer machine.  And it seems to only happen about 75% of the time.

WCF isn't my strongest aspect of .NET so any help pointing me in the correct direction would be useful.

Comment: Looks like I may have figured it out.  It would seem that one of the catch clauses was calling client.Close() instead of client.Abort().  client.Close() can throw an additional exception which was what was happening.  client.Abort() will not throw exceptions.

Comment: please post the solution as an answer and accept it by yourself.  It will remove your question from the "unanswered" ones.

Comment: Sorry about that, mkernbach.  Updated with an answer to get it out of the queue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue ended up being that inside a catch clause we had:

```
var proxy = new WcfProxy();

try
{
  // Do something.
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
  proxy.Close();
  throw;
}
```

Where the catch clause should have used proxy.Abort() as Close() can throw another exception.

```
catch (Exception ex)
{
  proxy.Abort();
  throw;
}
```